# Is this a valid way to use the Zarith Library

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I was wondering if this `Printf.printf "%d \n" Z.(s1 num2)` is a valid way to use the `Zarith` Library.
Don't know if more context is needed, but the function s1 is about Schroder sequence and when I use a number > 25 it won't show any number (because the number is way too big right? that's where `Zarith` enters) but I'm not sure if it is really working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I loaded Zarith into my OCaml toplevel (REPL for OCaml). Here's what I see if I try what you give:

```
# Printf.printf "%d\n" Z.(s1 num2);;
Error: Unbound value s1
```

This makes sense, there's no symbol named `s1` in the `Z` module (the big integer module of Zarith). If you have your own definition of `s1` you have to show its definition to get help with it.

If you want to print out a big integer, you can't print it as an integer (with %d format). You have to convert to a string and print that. Here is a toplevel session that prints out 2 ^ 101:

```
# #load "zarith.cma";;
# #load "zarith_top.cma";;
# let big = Z.(of_int 1 lsl 101);;
val big : Z.t = 2535301200456458802993406410752
# Printf.printf "{{%s}}" (Z.to_string big);;
{{2535301200456458802993406410752}}- : unit = ()
```

Comment: So basically the function has to be a big integer and to print the result it has to be a converted to a string?

Comment: You can't in general convert a big int (type Z.t) to a regular OCaml int, right? It can be far too large to represent as an int. So you can't print it with the %d format. Yes, you can convert it to a string and print the string (as in the example).